# Azure AD without Office 365

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm writing to ask for a simple question: would it be possible to use Azure AD (synced with on-premise Active Directory with AADConnect) without any Office 365 subscription ?

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create Azure AD tenants from the Azure portal if you have an Azure subscription.